# How can I get the max count in a Hive joined query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have this query:

```
select 

a.item_page_productid,
b.category_id,
a.viewcount

from 

(select 
item_page_productid,
count(*) as viewcount
from views 
where  eventdate > to_date(days_sub(now(), 60))
group by item_page_productid
) a

join

(select
 product_id,
 category_id
 from catalog_products_in_categories
 where active = 't') b

 on a.item_page_productid=b.category_id
```

What I am trying to do is pair a single item_page_productid with a single category_id with the item_page_productid paired being the one with the highest viewcount.

Any ideas?

Comment: would grouping by `item_page_productid, category_id` and taking `max(viewcount)` not work?

Comment: @GoBrewers14  I don't think so...  The above data returns duplicate category_id's because there are multiple item_page_productid per category_id and each item_page_productid has it's own viewcount score.   I'm not sure what Select item_page_productid, category_id and taking max(viewcount) would return for the item_page_productid but it would def return the maximum view count.

Comment: Okay.  It would be really helpful if you could edit your question and add a sample of what the data looks like and what you want the desired output to be.